# vlc plugin how to change audio track on live streaming

Tags: javascript, plugins, streaming, video-streaming, vlc

I use vlc plugin.

How to change audio track on live streaming channel?

I tried some code but no luck

```
<script type="text/javascript">
vlc.audio.track = "2";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
vlc.audio.track = 2;
</script>
```

Maybe some of you know working sentence. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Is there a way to find which audio track pid are used?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I meet same problem. If you know audio Pid it's simple to switch audio track. Code you wrote correct, just replace 2 with correct audio Pid.

```
var vlc = document.getElementById('vlc');
// Get current track
alert(vlc.audio.track);
// Set track
vlc.audio.track = 88; // be sure that this audio pid exist
```

Comment: And is there a way to make sure it exists?